# On a laravel app is it possible to have listener called only once, no matter how many times an event is being fired?

Tags: php, laravel

I think the title says it all.. In a Laravel app I'm dispatching an event (or events) multiple times in the code and have a subscriber for them, but I want it to process only once, no matter how many times the events are fired in the flow.

Is there any clear way to do that, or I am going to need a ..singleton class or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You can simply update your listener code and check(maybe based on data stored in DB or using some logs which you will store if executed successfully the first time), if already processed then do nothing otherwise process and log(or update).

Answer (score 1):

You could unlisten the event with `Event::forget('YourEvent');` in the subscriber after the first dispatch.

The downside is that all other listeners of this event will also be removed.

Comment: The downside could be avoided if I define additional event, fired on all of these events and caught by one certain listener only (and getting forgotten there). Not that clear as I was hoping, but will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason Event::forget('YourEvent'); put in the subscriber is not working. It processes as many times as the event is dispatched. At the end I made it with setting property in a singleton.

Comment: Did you use the correct event name? In case of Eloquent model events they are named "eloquent.updated:ModelClass" (example of updated event).

Comment: This may be valuable information for someone (I didn't know that) but actually I'm using just an ordinary event, dispatched in the code and calling it like Event::forget(MyEvent::class); Guess this forget is about to be forgotten in the other listeners that would listen for it next, but not by the one you're calling it from now..